# Add and remove the timepicker to the input field dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a timepicker to select the time with an interval of 15 minutes. I use the timepicker from [this link](http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/).

I am unable to add the timepicker to the input text field using the onclick function. Here is some sample code of what I am trying to achieve. Please help me solve this issue.

### index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="include/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.timepicker.css?v=0.3.0" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.timepicker.js?v=0.3.0"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .st{}
  .et{}
  #bod { font-size: small; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; }
  body{font-size:10px;}
  ......
  <div id="bod">
    <input type="text"  id="timepicker_start1" value="" class="st"/>
    <input type="text"  id="timepicker_end1" value=""  class="et"/>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="Add" name="Add" value="Add" onClick="add()" />
  <input type="hidden" id="tot" name="tot" value="1"/>
  ...
```

The javascript part of the page is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function add(){
    var tot=document.getElementById("tot").value;
    tot=parseInt(tot,10);
    var i=tot+1;
    $('#bod').append(i+".   ");
    var s=$('<input/>').attr({type:'text',id:'timepicker_start'+i}).addClass('st').appendTo("#bod");
    var s1=$('<input/>').attr({type:'text',id:'timepicker_end'+i}).addClass('et').appendTo("#bod");
    $('#bod').append("  ");
    $('#timepicker_start'+i).timpicker({showLeadingZero: true, defaultTime: '', minutes:{interval:15}});
    $('#timepicker_end'+i).timpicker({showLeadingZero: true, defaultTime: '', minutes:{interval:15}});
    document.getElementById("tot").value=i;
  }
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#timepicker_start1').timpicker({showLeadingZero: true, defaultTime: '', minutes:{interval:15}});
    $('#timepicker_end1').timpicker({showLeadingZero: true, defaultTime: '', minutes:{interval:15}});
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You got a typo: it's `timepicker` not `timpicker`.
Other than that you're good - the script is working - http://jsfiddle.net/FNww8/

Comment: Thanks.Actually the problem is not with the script. It is the timepicker. When i use id to call the timepicker function ,it shows error like object doesnt support this method..

Comment: What do you mean there's problem when calling timepicker with id? I showed you in my answer that it works - so?

Comment: I am extremely sorry, it is my mistake. Syntax error, I rectify it. Thanks for your correction. And one more suggestion needed, whether it is possible to add the timepicker on the input field onclick event..